# Counting vectors over finite fields (vector space)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

If $p$ is a prime,

1. Show that $\dfrac{\Bbb Z}{p^{n}\Bbb Z}$ is a vector space over $\dfrac{\Bbb Z}{p\Bbb Z}$ .
2. How many vectors are there in this vector space?

Comment: I did the first question . anyone could help with the second one ?

Comment: May be you could show what you did with part 1? Edit the question with your argument. That way you get feedback of what you did wrong (it is NOT a vector space). Also the question could then be reopened, and that would help your question block at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

(1) For $\;n>1\;,\;\;\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z\;$ is **not** a vector space over $\;\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ , because if it were then for all $\;w\in\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z\;$ we'd have that $\;0\cdot w=p\cdot w=0\;$, but this is impossible since $\;\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z\;$ is a cyclic group of order $\;p^n\;$ ...

(2) Zero.

Comment: @jhon96 Well, perhaps I am wrong...but can you rebut what I wrote? Because it looks like a mathematical proof to me.